# Wine GTA San Andreas problems

Tags: wine, games

So I installed Grand Theft Auto San Andreas (non-cd crack) with Wine.

But when I start it, the screen gets zoomed in the left part of the screen and I can't see anything. Can't close everything, nothing.

After a while, Wine gives an "fatal error" message.

I have to get the battery out of my laptop to restart it.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not clear on what you are asking. I certainly don't understand what "accu" means

Comment: Which Wine version do you use? Please run GTA:SA from a terminal and capture its output (along the lines of `WINEPREFIX=[…] wine gta-sa.exe |& tee gta-sa.log`), so you can post it here. You may get better help, if you report a bug at https://bugs.winehq.org/.

Comment: accu=akku=German word for battery. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry everyone, I tought accu was an English word. I mean batteries. I have to get the battery out of my laptop to turn it off. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidFoerster If I run the command (replacing [...] with the path to GTA SA), I get nothing. It doesn't start GTA, it doesn't give output. it literally does nothing.

Comment: For this to work you need to be in the installation directory of GTA:SA and set `WINEPREFIX` to the path of the Wine prefix, in which it is installed – *not* the installation directory inside the Wine prefix. The wine prefix is usually the path prefix *before* the `/drive_c/Program Files/…` part. Example: I installed Path of Exile in `$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/pathofexile/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Path of Exile` and need to set `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/pathofexile/"` to run it.

Comment: Non-CD crack?  Is this illegal software?

Comment: @Fabby hell ye why do you care anyways

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cracked software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [The Silent Patch](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=25368) to fix the resolution issue.

Comment: How did you install the patch?