# About installing "GTA: San Andreas" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

I am trying to play "Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas" on a Dell 15 5559 laptop with an i3 6th gen CPU, but whenever I try through wine or Play On Linux, screen size becomes smaller and display starts to hang, therefore I have to restart my laptop.

[image]

Is there any solution regarding this matter?
Kindly suggest how to install perfectly and play politely

Comment: What's your wine version? It may be the problem!

Comment: Also, specify the version of GTA San Andreas you are trying to play

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wine GTA San Andreas problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602082/wine-gta-san-andreas-problems)

Comment: wine 2.0 and now after some changes i can play the game smooth but display is not in full screen.i tried through wine display configuration but no change.now what to do in that matter

Comment: I'm not sure about this problem, however, this is another question. Please, if my answer was helpful in some way accept it, and ask another question if you have different issue, as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WineHQ AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2599) `Grand Theft Auto : San Andreas` should work fine.
However there might be cases where GTA refuses to open :

> Some times gta may fail to start even when you haven't touched (modded) anything. In this case delete the file gta_sa.set inside  the Documents/GTA San Andreas User Files directory and restart the app. You will have to reset your gta sa settings.

Anyway it seems that the version of `GTA:SA` with less issue is the STEAM one (v3.00), as you can see [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=15325).

---

**EDIT :** It seems that other users has the same issue you describe.
The solution should be as easy as installing [SilentPatch](https://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=25368).

[*Source*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602082/wine-gta-san-andreas-problems?rq=1)